# Novell iPrint Client delays Windows login

Tags: novell, windows

At the University I work at, we have a system in which every student gets a laptop and this laptop comes installed with the Novell iPrint client to allow for wireless printing throughout campus.

This year the laptops the students are receiving will have SSDs installed. These new drives allow for Windows to load in just about 15 seconds. We are very pleased with this performance. But, that good performance disappears when we install Novell iPrint. When Novell iPrint is installed the boot time goes from 15 seconds to 45 seconds. This boot time will revert to 15 seconds if we uninstall iPrint. So the delay is directly related to something Novell iPrint is doing during startup.

The delay occurs during the "Welcome" screen phase of the logon process. We used Windows Performance Development tools to monitor the startup process. We have narrowed down the problem and it is occurring during the Winlogon.init phase of the startup. If the computer does not have iPrint installed this phase takes a few seconds. When you install iPrint this phase takes 30 seconds or more.

We know where this problem is occurring but we have yet to track down what is causing this problem and if there is a solution. We have spent multiple days researching and troubleshooting. I tried disabling all the services and startup programs related to Novell and (even the print spooler) but this delay is still apparent and unchanged.

We assume the problem is something network related and something waiting for a timeout to occur. No error messages ever appear and the application successfully launches on startup, after making the computer wait 30 seconds for some unknown reason. Though, we tried with and without wifi and with and without the network adapters installed; nothing is stopping this 30 second delay from occurring or even improving.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is with the user login time, not boot time. You don't want to confuse the two; they are different.

Try this : http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3386741

> Situation
>
> When a WAN link to servers holding [Root] is down, the Novell Client
> for Windows login will be slow if the iPrint Client is installed on
> the workstation.  Resolution
>
> Install the iPrint client using nipp-sl.exe.  Each iPrint client
> install includes various exe options, nipp-sl being one of them.  See
> the iPrint client readme for more information.   As a workaround,
> follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open regedit
> 2. Go to this key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Novell\Graphical Login\NWLGE\iPrint
> 3. Remove the iPrint key (folder)
>
> Note: Implementing this workaround will disable the client's ability
> to use iCM, auto-upgrade QMS to iPrint, auto-upgrade NDPS to iPrint,
> and other iPrint features that rely on tree walking.

Comment: This has been attempted, no change has occurred.

Comment: OK, it helps if you detail what things you've done already :-)

Comment: As I mentioned I tried delaying and or disabling Novell related services and programs from starting. I attempted multiple times your suggestion of using nipp-sl.exe. I tried numerous registry tweaks that I came across during my research. I examined as much as I could the windows boot process and startup using the developer tools from Microsoft, this is how I narrowed down the problem to the winlogon.init phase. I tried connecting the computer via LAN to the network and than I eliminated the network altogether to attempt to narrow things down.

Comment: Have you contacted Novell support?

Comment: We have posted on their support forums, nothing as of yet. We have gotten into contact with other Universities that use iPrint, and we are waiting on a reply. We may try to find a more direct way to get into contact with Novell tomorrow if nothing else helps.